# Merge two unordered generic array lists

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm attempting to create a merge and split method to add to these:

```
public interface ArrayListADT<T> extends Cloneable {
public boolean isEmpty(); 
public boolean isFull(); 
public int listSize(); 
public int maxListSize();
public void print();
public Object clone(); 
public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, T item); 
public void insertAt(int location, T insertItem); 
public void insertEnd(T insertItem); 
public void removeAt(int location); 
public T retrieveAt(int location); 
public void replaceAt(int location, T repItem);
public void clearList(); 
public int search(T searchItem); 
public void remove(T removeItem); 
}
```

The merge method should concatenate two unordered array list into a 3rd. The two lists have no keys in common. The third list should have all items from list one and two. The ordered should also be preserved.

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> UnorderedArrayList<T>     merge(UnorderedArrayList<T> list, UnorderedArrayList<T> list2){
for (int index2 = 0; index2 < list2.listSize(); index2++) {
    for (int index1 = 0; ; index1++) {
        if (index1 == list.listSize() || list.retrieveAt(index1) > list2.retrieveAt(index2)) {
            list.add(index1, list2.get(index2));
            break;
```

I'm getting a bad operand types for >.. Should I implement a compareTo method?

For the split method here's what I have.

```
public void split(UnorderedArrayList list, UnorderedArrayList list2, UnorderedArrayList list3, int key) {
int num = 0;
list.clearList();
list2.clearList();
for(int i = 0;i < list3.length; i++) {
  num = list3.retrieveAt(i);
  if(num <= key) 
    list.insertEnd(num);
  else
    list2.insertEnd(num);
```

I'm getting an error on `num = list3.retrieveAt(i);` 
Error: Object cannot be converted to int. Do I need to type-cast it to an int?

Comment: What's `UnorderedArrayList`? Is it `ArrayListADT`?

Comment: It's a class that extends from `ArrayListClass` and that's an abstract class that implements `ArrayListADT` . @TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I implement a `compareTo` method?

Well, `Comparable` (which `T` is required to be) already has one. So you use it, yes:

```
if (index1 == list.listSize() || list.retrieveAt(index1).compareTo(list2.retrieveAt(index2)) > 0) {
```

If you're writing a class to use as `T`, then yes, you need to implement `compareTo` to satisfy the `Comparable` contract.